# Passing data to new workbench window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am opening a new workbench window using

```java
WindowInput windowInput = new WindowInput();
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().openWorkbenchWindow(perspective_id, windowInput);
```

Below is my `WindowInput` class:

```java
public class WindowInput implements IAdaptable {

    @Override
    public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
        System.err.println("inside getAdapter");
        if (adapter == java.util.HashMap.class) {
            HashMap<String, List<String>> fieldsMap = new HashMap<>();
            fieldsMap.put("key1",getRecordsString());
            fieldsMap.put("key2",getRecordsString());
            return fieldsMap;
        }
        return null;
     }
}
```

now, when I am trying to get the Map in newly opened workbench window using

```java
HashMap<String,List<String>> fieldsMap = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getAdapter(HashMap.class);
```

the fieldsMap is still null. I cannot even see the "System.err.println("inside getAdapter");" printing something on console, concluding "getAdapter" is not getting called.

Can someone help me with this please.

Basically, I am trying to pass data between two workbench windows.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is asking the `IWorkbench` object for a `HashMap` but this is not where the object passed to `openWorkbenchWindow` ends up.

The input to `openWorkbenchWindow` is passed to the new `IWorkbenchWindow`. This in turn passes the input on to the `IWorkbenchPage` objects in the window.

If your code is in a view part in a workbench page in the new workbench window you can get the input with:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = getPage();

// The page input should be your WindowInput
IAdaptable adaptable = page.getInput();

HashMap<String,List<String>> fieldsMap = adaptable.getAdapter(HashMap.class);
```

Comment: Ahhhh ! Tried many things , never ever was near this "page" thing....
Thank you very much Greg, it worked !

Comment: You need to start Accepting answers that answer your questions - click the tick mark next to the answer.